# Azure Mobile Services / Authentication

Tags: authentication, mobile, azure, service, azure-mobile-services

We're trying to use the mobile services authentication for a cross-platform mobile app.  The User object returned, nicely provides the ID, but that's it.

```
user = await client.LoginAsync(this, MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider.Google);
```

We need the user's name and, ideally, email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you're fine using a preview feature, they've just introduced enhanced user services...check out 
[Enhanced users feature in Azure Mobile Services](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2013/12/16/enhanced-users-feature-in-azure-mobile-services.aspx)

Comment: Very timely!  Thanks.  The enhanced Users Features for Azure detailed in the article works well.  It's a preview feature, but after the user is authenticated with the ID, a custom api call (Azure Mobile Services), pulls the additional user information back as a JSON object.

Answer (score 1):

You will be using the OAuth , in which Windows Live, Google, Facebook and Twitter will be the way in which you have options of connecting users.

I needed to get more information on user and thus I wrote a question and ended up using the LoginAsync, but then 2 other things were CRITICAL for me to get more information

```
var userInfo = await MobileServices.MobileService.InvokeApiAsync(
"userInfo", HttpMethod.Get, null);
```

Then

```
with a Custom API - node.js code
```

THEN an area in the portal with adding "SCOPE" which in Azure portal is like a web.config / app.config  , then I was able to get email address (it does warn the user about it sharing this information, which is normal)

**Visit this link:**
[Azure Mobile Services - Getting more user information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23160940/azure-mobile-services-getting-more-user-information)